# Closures vs returning an value/object from a function

Tags: swift, function, architecture, closures, swift4

I'm currently learning Swift(4)/iOS programming. I'm fairly new to OOP, but do have experience in Functional programming. There's one concept that confuses me somewhat...

In the courses/examples I followed a function mostly looks like this:

```
func getUsername(forUid uid: String, handler: @escaping (_ username: String) -> Void) {
//Do stuff    
handler("MyName")
}
```

The name is passed by the closure, I hardly ever see a function like this:

```
func getUsername(forUid uid: String) -> String) {
//Do stuff    
 return "MyName"
}
```

Is the second way deprecated, or is there still a use for such a function. When and why do we use the first variant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the first variant for asynchronous programming. For example, see

```
func getUsername(forUid uid: String, handler: @escaping (_ username: String) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // do some asynchronous stuff
        handler("MyName")
    }
}
```

Note `handler` *has* to be inside the `async` closure or else the handler will be called immediately because `async` does not block. Now if we used `return` instead of `handler`, there will be a compile error because your function doesn't return any value, so to fix the compile error it has to be in the function level (not in the `async` block). If it's not in the `async` block, it will be returned immediately (same as the second `handler` case above, so you *must* use closures if you are doing asynchronous tasks. However, if you are not using asynchronous stuff, you can safely use the second variant in your code.

In addition to asynchronous programming, closures are used in synchronous programming too, for example, the [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) function uses a closure as a parameter to define how should the object be mapped.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just not totally used to the asynchronous stuff, hence the confusion. But clear now :)

Comment: @paper1111 A closure is not limited to asynchronous behaviour. It can behave synchronously as well depending on the context. Ease of asynchronousity is just one application of closures.

Comment: @justintime I have just added a paragraph about synchronous closures.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not deprecated.
You should use closures for async tasks otherwise return value.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to get it with an example. Here's I get some places from an API:

```
func getPlaces(onSuccess: @escaping(_ places: [Place]?) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error, _ title: String?, _ message: String?) -> Void) {
    //perform API request...
    //[...]
    //...
        // Session
        session.dataTask(with: requestURL) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {

                //handling Error
                onFailure(error!, "Error", error?.localizedDescription)
                group.leave()
                return
            }
            //...
            //handling succes
            else {
                var places: [Place] = []

                places = responseJson.places!
                onSuccess(places)
            }
            group.leave()
            }.resume()
    }
    group.wait()
    return
}
```

As you can see I want to handle success and error. Here's how I use it:

```
APIManager.shared.getPlaces(onSuccess: { (places) in
          //handling success
        }
    }) { (error, title, message) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(getAlertFromError(title: title, message: message), animated: true)
        }
    }
```